# Safe value must use [property]=binding after http interceptor and bypass security with DomSanitizer

Tags: javascript, angular

```
<!--HTML CODE-->
<svg style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<image #cameraImage
       (load)="adjustImageSize()"
       (click)="clickOnImage($event)"
       [attr.href]="imageUrl | secureUrl | async"></image>
</svg>

// pipe code
@Pipe({
    name: 'secureUrl'
})
export class SecureUrlPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }
    transform(url): Observable<SafeUrl> {
        return this.http
            .get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
            .pipe(map((e) =>                 this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(`url(${URL.createObjectURL(e)})`)));
    }
}
```

but the image is not getting displayed, when inspect console getting security error 400 bad request:-

SafeValue%20must%20use%20[property]=binding:%20url(blob:https://

although can see image response in Network. Please suggest where am doing wrong.

svg image should get displayed

Comment: Looks like you've encountered a [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38854) in Angular that throws this error when binding to an attribute `[attr.href]` within SVG. This issue does not occur when property binding is used. (*which doesn't help in your case because there's no 'href' property*). :-\

Comment: Right, have apply workaround suggested in bug thread. Now <image [attr.href]="data:image/png;base64, iVBOR...."> put unsanitized URL in base64.